# How can I compare two lists of strings from two people without sharing the actual strings between people?

Tags: string, hash, comparison, string-comparison

For example, how can the owner of list A compare identify how many of their strings exist in List B without ever seeing List B?

```
List A            List B
abcdef            abcdef
ghijkl            mnopqr
stuvwx            stuvwx
yz0123
```

The result should be two.  As in, List A has 2 strings found in List B.  This is easy enough if lists are shared in open text.  But how can this answer be found without the owner of List A seeing List B?

Comment: You could hash them and compare the hashes -- just a thought.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by 'seeing'

Comment: Is there a security issue that prevents the owners from seeing each other's lists? Is it OK for the owner of A to know which strings in his list matched in list B?

Comment: Re: John -- owner of list A should never be able to see the open text string "mnopqr". (for example)

Comment: Re: Jonathan -- ideally not, only the overlap/duplicate count is critical, but only if it's possible.

Comment: @Ryan, is it OK for a 3rd party system (like a web server you control) to know the contents of both users' lists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hash the strings in the two lists and then compare the hashes.

Answer (score 0):

If users A and B are peers with no real "system" to handle the transactions between them, then:

1. Each user enters their list into their session or client software.
2. The session or client software hashes the members of the list.
3. The session or client software then queries a database for matching hashes from user B.
4. If other users need to compare their lists with user A, the session or client software stores all hashes for user A's list in the database under records for user A.

However, if there *is* a real system (server) between the two users, it is able to see everyone's list entries and communicate matches back to the users.